# Fixed Page Header

Tags: css, fixed

I've never dealt with CSS but now I have to. I'm developing some HTML code - a sketch of a website and have a problem with CSS. I would like to have my header in a fixed position, I mean it always should be on the top of the site, even if there is so much content that site has to be scrolled to see everything. I've tried somethig, but it does not work properly.

HTML:

```css
    body {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    header {
        border: 2px solid red;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #top-menu-bar {
        border: 1px dashed red;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    #main-menu-bar {
        border: 1px dashed red;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    #logo-bar {
        border: 1px dashed red;
        padding: 35px;
    }

    #content {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    footer {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"></link>
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div id="top-menu-bar">
         Login &nbsp; | &nbsp; Registration
          </div>
          <div id="logo-bar">
         LOGO
          </div>
          <div id="main-menu-bar">
                MenuItem1 &nbsp; | &nbsp; MenuItem3 &nbsp; | &nbsp; MenuItem3
          </div>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
          <h1>
            Content
          </h1>
          <p>
            Some content<br/>
          </p>
        </div>
        <footer>
       Footer
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

if you still do not get it what I mean, here I provide links [with fixed,](http://students.wmi.amu.edu.pl/~s329488/stackoverflow/fixed.html) [witout fixed](http://students.wmi.amu.edu.pl/~s329488/stackoverflow/notfixed.html)

Of course, what I'm looking for is nice a solution, without unnecessary code (even CSS and JS). It is important to note that no one element, especially header has not fixed height!

Comment: You want the header to be always fixed to the top of the browser window, but the content to onyl go under it when the window is scrolled, correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to add the following CSS to your header to make it stay at the top of the page:

```
top: 0px;
```

Then, with `div#content`, give it a top margin to push it down out of the header's way:

```
margin-top: 200px;
```

So your CSS ends up looking like this:

```
header {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
}

#content {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo reply. but why in the #content { margin-top: 200px } ? I said that header has no fixed height, so if header would have for example 250px in height then this soultion fails.

Comment: That's the one downfall of this technique. Because `position: fixed` elements are removed from the normal flow, you have to manually position things underneath them. You can't do it another way.

Comment: I've already tried the solution you proposed. I was just curious if it is possible to get what I need by bypassing fixed height property. I don't know how, but I have got hunch that some css guru would do that :D Nevertheless, thanx!

Comment: Not a problem. I'm actually working on a site with a similar layout and yes, not having to do things on a per-pixel basis would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Add fixed height to header, and use the same value for padding-top of content.

See http://jsfiddle.net/DmLkQ/

If you don't want fixed height, use jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/DmLkQ/5/

Comment: OK, that's not a perfect solution I was looking for. I mean I've already tried this, but I don't like the fact the header has fixed height. Nevertheless, thank you :)

Comment: Ah, then it's not possible - as @JamWaffles mentioned. You could do it with jQuery though, by first checking the height of the header, and then passing this height to padding-top...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```