# How to fix main navigation on top when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, html

First, Merry Christmas to all

I want to fix my top navigation menu bar on top when scrolling down like : [csschopper.com](http://csschopper.com)

this happen by  `position: fixed;` css property but when i put it in css menu will be fixed at top. this will require some javascript code but I don't know what exactly the code is. also when someone scroll down i also want to display small logo beside the menu like [csschopper.com](http://csschopper.com)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326665/fixed-page-header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the code would look like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/CCmFR/) In this example I created two navigation bars but you can also have one and then add an item

This is jQuery code, so make sure to load the jQuery libery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: amazing example... really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Initial position of topbar is static. But when user scroll (you have to catch onscroll event) like this on jquery :

```
$(window).scroll(function());
```

with a scroll position bigger than header height, the Javascript modifiy the topbar position to fixed with this for example :

```
documentById().style.display
```

The same thing for the logo on left.