# HTML/CSS Make header and nav sticky on top of the page

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

Currently working on a web project, I would like to set up a sticky part on my website
that could be always available. I tried different things but nothing worked.

My structure is like below

```
<body>
  <wrap>
    <header></header>
    <nav></nav>
    <container></container>
  </wrap>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

If you prefer a scheme, it's this link:
http://s21.postimg.org/79tp8wu5z/structure_page.png

So I want to make my header nav and background (which is applied on body background) sticky on top of the page.

I know I need to use the fixed an relative position but nothing works except the background.

Here is my css:

```
body {
  background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top;
}

.wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  height: 121px;
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #146992;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
}

#menu {
  position:relative;
  height: 45px;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are a dozen of examples about this topic here in Stackoverflow!

Comment: *...but nothing works*. How exactly it doesn't work? Could you share a demo page?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326665/fixed-page-header

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't fixed the position of the `nav` bar. 
Try using

```
#nav
 {
 background-color:#262626;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}
```

Or you can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) for startup.

Look [here](http://thecodepress.blogspot.in/2013/01/fixed-navigation-bar-in-css-html.html) and [here](http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/simple-steps-for-creating-a-fixed-navigation-bar/).

Answer (score 8):

I have myself been looking into this problem. I have seen quite a few solutions and each of them had issues, often involving some magic numbers.

So using best practices from various sources I came up with a solution:

The thing i wanted to achieve specifically here was to get the main content to scroll between footer and header inside green area.

Here is working demo with source code:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    height: 4em;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
.content {
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:5em;
    bottom:5em;
    overflow:auto;
}
.contentinner {

}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: -4em 0 -2em 0;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
footer {
    height: 2em;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>Header Strip</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="contentinner">
            <p>THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT GOES</p>
            <p><a href="http://traceyspencer.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/css-sticky-header-and-footer-with.html" target="_blank">CLICK HERE for an explanation of this page</a>.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis lectus nibh, bibendum sit amet porttitor ut, pretium id lectus. Nulla facilisis erat vel nisi malesuada consequat. Phasellus ac porta enim. Aliquam feugiat, lacus ornare fringilla sodales, neque arcu ultricies lorem, vel rhoncus lacus purus eu est. Proin sodales suscipit elit, ut consectetur erat faucibus a. Integer gravida, odio sed pellentesque cursus, lorem mi gravida nisi, vel consequat leo turpis vel leo. Vestibulum ac purus quam. Donec imperdiet varius mollis. Aliquam adipiscing magna vitae ipsum aliquam blandit. Morbi lectus purus, tempor vitae laoreet eu, sollicitudin sit amet magna.</p>
            <p>Donec eu vulputate libero. Praesent justo tortor, lobortis sed eleifend nec, posuere a tellus. Sed at purus vitae diam molestie dictum sed quis dolor. Nam pulvinar mi neque, fermentum vehicula arcu. Aenean fringilla, dui non blandit luctus, ligula leo aliquam justo, ac fermentum felis nisi ut mauris. Duis tristique lacinia molestie. In quam sem, tristique non aliquam id, luctus vitae tellus. Cras a mollis sapien.</p>
            <p>Donec vel justo vel sem consectetur tempor nec ut est. Nullam fermentum fringilla ultricies. Donec hendrerit condimentum vestibulum. Nulla bibendum urna congue augue semper vitae ultricies dui egestas. Fusce quis risus nibh, nec sagittis ipsum. Sed metus massa, adipiscing quis pharetra ac, sagittis non tellus. Praesent at dolor a est vehicula porttitor. Aenean nec sodales felis.</p>
            <p>Vestibulum ut ornare elit. Quisque nisl sem, scelerisque vitae egestas vel, interdum eget augue. Etiam dapibus pharetra ligula, eget imperdiet mi blandit sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Cras auctor pulvinar augue nec ultrices. Integer congue cursus est, vitae pulvinar quam mattis ut. Aliquam quis dui tincidunt ipsum tristique vulputate vel vitae mauris. Vivamus facilisis rutrum justo, ac sagittis est dapibus sit amet. Sed tortor libero, congue sed egestas et, tempus in urna. Nunc tellus metus, condimentum sed luctus ut, eleifend ac mi. Praesent et tincidunt justo. Suspendisse facilisis elit nec dui sodales sit amet semper mi elementum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            <p>Morbi nec ante at sapien semper varius. Etiam a felis in erat vehicula vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel magna eu enim cursus mollis. Donec orci tellus, feugiat ut vulputate in, congue eu diam. Nulla pulvinar hendrerit elit in ornare. Praesent malesuada facilisis convallis. Vestibulum vel sem vel mauris dapibus tempor nec quis erat. Aenean mattis ultricies mauris et rutrum. Mauris ac justo eros, et semper mi.</p>
            <p>Donec eu vulputate libero. Praesent justo tortor, lobortis sed eleifend nec, posuere a tellus. Sed at purus vitae diam molestie dictum sed quis dolor. Nam pulvinar mi neque, fermentum vehicula arcu. Aenean fringilla, dui non blandit luctus, ligula leo aliquam justo, ac fermentum felis nisi ut mauris. Duis tristique lacinia molestie. In quam sem, tristique non aliquam id, luctus vitae tellus. Cras a mollis sapien.</p>
            <p>Donec vel justo vel sem consectetur tempor nec ut est. Nullam fermentum fringilla ultricies. Donec hendrerit condimentum vestibulum. Nulla bibendum urna congue augue semper vitae ultricies dui egestas. Fusce quis risus nibh, nec sagittis ipsum. Sed metus massa, adipiscing quis pharetra ac, sagittis non tellus. Praesent at dolor a est vehicula porttitor. Aenean nec sodales felis.</p>
            <p>Vestibulum ut ornare elit. Quisque nisl sem, scelerisque vitae egestas vel, interdum eget augue. Etiam dapibus pharetra ligula, eget imperdiet mi blandit sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Cras auctor pulvinar augue nec ultrices. Integer congue cursus est, vitae pulvinar quam mattis ut. Aliquam quis dui tincidunt ipsum tristique vulputate vel vitae mauris. Vivamus facilisis rutrum justo, ac sagittis est dapibus sit amet. Sed tortor libero, congue sed egestas et, tempus in urna. Nunc tellus metus, condimentum sed luctus ut, eleifend ac mi. Praesent et tincidunt justo. Suspendisse facilisis elit nec dui sodales sit amet semper mi elementum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            <p>Morbi nec ante at sapien semper varius. Etiam a felis in erat vehicula vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel magna eu enim cursus mollis. Donec orci tellus, feugiat ut vulputate in, congue eu diam. Nulla pulvinar hendrerit elit in ornare. Praesent malesuada facilisis convallis. Vestibulum vel sem vel mauris dapibus tempor nec quis erat. Aenean mattis ultricies mauris et rutrum. Mauris ac justo eros, et semper mi.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

please don't use position fixed if you create a responsive website. because it creates a problem in 
Webkit browsers and iPhone & iPad. personally I suggest you to use [Page Scroller](http://pagescroller.com) this helps you to Easily and Smooth scroll for Client.